# Custom Moon/sun texture minecraft mod 1.18.2

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm currently working on a forge mod for 1.18.2, I don't really know anything about java, I just want to replace the sun and moon textures for my custom dimension, I've been searching for day to find an answer and that has gotten me nowhere, I really need help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to change the texture of sun and moon you first need to create a texture pack and then include it in your mod.

First create a custom texture pack.

Then in the `YourTexturePack\assets\minecraft\textures\environment`.

Change the `sun.png` and the `moon.png` with you custom textures.

Now That You Have The Texture Pack Ready You Need To Put It In Your Mod.

Copy the `assets` folder of your texture pack, And paste it in the
`src\main\` of your mod folder.

I hope that helped you